# ImportError: cannot import name Celery with gunicorn

Tags: django, python-2.7, celery, gunicorn

With command ...
`manage.py runserver` run it successfully 
but

```
gunicorn  edx_lms.wsgi:application -b 127.0.0.1:8090 --timeout 1200




2016-02-12 13:15:20 [27341] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 473, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 115, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 33, in load
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 362, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/EDX/edx_lms/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .celery_tasks import app as celery_app
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/EDX/edx_lms/celery_tasks.py", line 4, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/EDX/edx_lms/celery.py", line 3, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
ImportError: cannot import name Celery
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 473, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 115, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 33, in load
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 362, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/EDX/edx_lms/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .celery_tasks import app as celery_app
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/EDX/edx_lms/celery_tasks.py", line 4, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/EDX/edx_lms/celery.py", line 3, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
ImportError: cannot import name Celery
2016-02-12 13:15:20 [27341] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 27341)
2016-02-12 13:15:20 [27336] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2016-02-12 13:15:20 [27336] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.`
```

Comment: Have you tried installing Celery? `pip install celery`

Comment: yes, celery is install.

Comment: where is celery installed? are any of the components using virtualenvs?

Comment: are you doing this for edx? if yes, then you can try "sudo su edxapp -s /bin/bash" followed by "cd ~", followed by "source edxapp_env" and then try to run your desired command.